# How to sample recent articles from Alchemy DataNews API?

Tags: ibm-cloud, alchemyapi

Does anyone know how I can query the Alchemy News API to retrieve a sample of all articles within the last 24 hours, up to the specified count number? Yesterday, I was using the query below to get 1,000 articles with concepts extracted, and it was working fine. However, for some reason the same query today is only giving ~24 results.

```
https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/data/GetNews?
apikey=<APIKEY>&outputMode=json&start=now-1d&
end=now&count=1000&
return=enriched.url.url,enriched.url.title,
enriched.url.concepts.concept.text,enriched.url.concepts.concept.relevance
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have been a temporary issue, possibly there was some kind of maintenance taking place.  Same requests returns 1000 results today.